# ElasticSearch - search using abbreviations

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am trying to setup an existing/custom analyzer that enable search using abbreviations. For example, if the text field is "Bank Of America", searching for BOfA or BOA, BofA etc should match this record.

How can I do that?

Comment: user3775217's answer should be given the check as it answers your question.

Answer (score 2):

You can probably use [synonym filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-synonym-tokenfilter.html) token for a custom analyzer.

For example the following mappings

```
{
"settings": {
    "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
            "my_analyzer": {
                "tokenizer": "standard",
                "filter": ["lowercase", "synonym_filter"]
            }
        },
        "filter": {
            "synonym_filter": {
                "type": "synonym",
                "synonyms": [
                    "bank of america,boa"
                ],
                "expand": true
            }
        }
    }
},
"mappings": {
    "document": {
        "properties": {
            "text": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
                "fielddata": true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Definitely you can add more to the list or use a synonym file.

For query usecases BOfA or BOA, BofA - two approaches can be worked.

1) More synonyms with these possible combination

```
 "synonyms": [
                    "bank of america,boa"
                    "bank of america,bofa"
                ]
```

2) or keep the abrevations intact and use fuzzy query

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "text" : {
        "query": "bofa",
        "fuzziness": 2
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You will need synoyms to supply abrevations to ES.

Answer (score 2):

I figure out something approaching using pattern_replace:

```
GET /_analyze
{
  "tokenizer": "keyword",
  "filter": [
    {
      "type": "pattern_replace",
      "pattern": "(\\B.)",
      "replacement": ""
    },
    {
      "type": "pattern_replace",
      "pattern": "(\\s)",
      "replacement": ""
    },
    "uppercase",
    {
      "type": "ngram",
      "min_gram": 3,
      "max_gram": 5
    }
  ],
  "text": "foxes jump lazy dogs"
}
```

which produces:

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "FJL",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 20,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "FJLD",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 20,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "JLD",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 20,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Great solution! One thing I needed to do was increase the `max_ngram_diff` in the index settings because it defaults to `1`.